# Pygame character does not show up on screen

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

I try to get my Pygame  character on screen but I cannot get it to appear so I can control it for a game I am building
Here is the code:

```html
import pygame
#turn on pygame

pygame.init()

#window, window name and icon
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920,1080))

pygame.display.set_caption("When The Sky Turns Grey")
icon = pygame.image.load('cat.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

#Player
playerIMG = pygame.image.load('cat.png')
playerX = 960
playerY = 1080
playerXchange = 0

def player():
    screen.blit(playerIMG, (playerX, playerY))

#Game loop

running = True
while running:
   
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        #KEYS
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                playerX_change = -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                playerX_change = 5
                


        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                playerXchange = 0

    playerX += playerXchange        
    #RGB
    screen.fill((0, 0, 255))
    #draw player (call player function)
    player()
    

    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    pygame.display.update()
```

I cannot get it to show up at all, no matter what I change.
I am new to pygame and if anyone can help I will be grateful
Thank you!
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: blit draws the image starting at the top left. You are drawing it just outside the bounds of the screen (960, 1080). Reduce the Y value.

Comment: Try `screen.blit(playerIMG, (playerX, playerY - playerIMG.get_height()))` to shift the y position by the height of the image.

Comment: Thank you! it works

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 problems in this question

First your cat Y position is to much that it went under the screen, it should be like this:

```py
playerY = 540 # Don't go over 1080 which is the screen height
```

Second you didn't update the display so it doesn't show anything on the screen, at the very end of the while loop put `pygame.display.update` after `player()`